# How do I get detailed logs about what object was passed to a mocked method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I ran into a failing unit test in a complex piece of code and the Moq logging wasn't doing it for me. I need to know what's different between what I expected a method to be called with and what it was actually called with. I ended up attaching a debugger to the unit test and that way I could look into the object being passed to the moq and manually compare all its values. All this effort would not be neccesary if I got more information from the `Verify` error message.

How do I log the differences between these two things?

- What I expected the mocked method to be called with
- What the mocked method was actually called with

A simplified example:

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using Moq;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    [TestClass]
    public class MyTestClass
    {
        [TestMethod]
        public void MyTestMethod()
        {
            // Arrange
            var serviceMock = new Mock<IService>();
            var model = new Model
            {
                Word = "Foo",
                Number = 1
            };
            var servicecaller = new ServiceCaller(serviceMock.Object);

            // Act
            servicecaller.CallService(model);

            // Assert
            serviceMock.Verify(mock =>
                mock.Call(
                    It.Is<Model>(m =>
                        m.Word == "Bar"
                        && m.Number == 1)));
        }
    }

    public class ServiceCaller
    {
        private IService _service;
        public ServiceCaller(IService service)
        {
            _service = service;
        }

        public void CallService(Model model)
        {
            _service.Call(model);
        }
    }

    public interface IService
    {
        void Call(Model model);
    }

    public class Model
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Word { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When you run this test, it fails and shows this message:

> ```
> Test method MyNamespace.MyTestClass.MyTestMethod threw exception: 
> Moq.MockException: 
> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never performed: mock => mock.Call(It.Is<Model>(m => m.Word == "Bar" && m.Number == 1))
> No setups configured.
>
> Performed invocations: 
> IService.Call(Model)
> ```

But I want it to log something along the lines of:

> ```
> Performed invocations: 
> IService.Call(Model { Word: "Bar", Number: 1 })
> ```

Or even better:

> ```
> "Assert failed for the object passed to IService.Call: The Model.Word 'Foo' is not equal to 'Bar'".
> ```

Comment: You can [provide a custom error message](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#verification).

Comment: I've tried adding a custom error message, but you can't access the object passed to the mocked method from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll probably have to verify the invocations via `Mock.Invocations` which is a sequence of all invocations on the mock along with the arguments that were provided. Something like the following:

```
var callInvocations = serviceMock.Invocations.Where(x => x.Method.Name.Equals(nameof(IService.Call)));
var matchingInvocations = callInvocations.Where(x =>
{
    var model = x.Arguments.First() as Model;
    return model.Word.Equals("Bar") && model.Number == 1;
});

if (!matchingInvocations.Any())
{   
    throw new Exception($"Performed invocations:{Environment.NewLine}{string.Join(Environment.NewLine, callInvocations.Select(x => $"{x.Method.DeclaringType.Name}.{x.Method.Name}({string.Join(", ", x.Method.GetParameters().Select((y, i) => $"{y.ParameterType.Name} {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x.Arguments[i])}"))})"))}");
}
```

will give the desired output:

[image]

Comment: I don't see a public "Invocations" property on the mock. Where did you get that from?

Comment: I've noticed we're using Moq 4.8.2 while there is  4.14.5 available. Were the invocations recently added?

Comment: Ah yeah, it was added in a recent version. I've got it now I've updated it.